# Rails Precompilation: Why a LESS.ERB file doesn't work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, less, asset-pipeline, erb

I'm trying to use Rails Asset Pipeline to work with a less.erb file.

Before I used LESS, I used SCSS. With SCSS I could have SCSS.ERB files. Everything worked perfectly.

Unfortanately, the UI Framework that I want to use (Semantic-UI) doesn't support SCSS, only LESS.

So I changed:

Added these gems:

```
gem 'less-rails', '~> 2.7.0'
gem 'therubyracer', '~> 0.12.2'
gem 'less-rails-semantic_ui', '~> 2.0.7'
```

Then I add _colors.less.erb file to my asset pipeline (in assets/stylesheets/core/_colors.less.erb), with this content:

```
@import "variables/_colors.less";

<% colors_list = %w(primary secondary gray green red blue yellow purple orange brown violet pink olive teal) %>


/*--------------------
   Background Colors
---------------------*/

<% colors_list.each do |color| %>
  .bg-color-<%=color%>         { background-color: @color-<%=color%>; }
  .bg-color-<%=color%>-darker  { background-color: @color-<%=color%>-darker; }
  .bg-color-<%=color%>-dark    { background-color: @color-<%=color%>-dark; }
  .bg-color-<%=color%>-light   { background-color: @color-<%=color%>-light; }
  .bg-color-<%=color%>-lighter { background-color: @color-<%=color%>-lighter; }
<% end %>

.bg-color-black         { background-color: @color-black; }
.bg-color-white         { background-color: @color-white; }
.bg-color-gray-darkest  { background-color: @color-gray-darkest; }
.bg-color-gray-lightest { background-color: @color-gray-lightest; }
```

The problem here is that, unlike scss.erb files, these less.erb files are not precompiled from erb to less.

It returns the error: 'core/_colors.less' wasn't found

**Does anyone know why this happens?**

Comment: On the latest version of Rails, a `app/assets/stylesheets/test.less.erb` file gets run through ERB like expected and put into the compiled application.css, no problem. What version of Rails are you on? What version of Sprockets is it using?

Comment: I'm using Rails 4.2.3, sprockets (3.2.0) and sprockets-rails (2.3.2).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but you say the "_colors.less" is in "assets/stylesheets/core/_colors.less.erb" and you import from "variables/_colors.less"

I think your import should be "core/_colors.less"

Comment: Sorry. I've two _colors.less files. One in core/_colors.less where i put all less code and another in core/variables/_colors.less where i put only variables.